# React Native (Typescript) Absolute path unable to resolve module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, import

I have just created a new project and I am trying to setup an absolute path by following this post: https://medium.com/geekculture/making-life-easier-with-absolute-imports-react-in-javascript-and-typescript-bbdab8a8a3a1

I have followed the steps as close as I can but can not get this to work in my simulator. (Visually there are no errors when looking at my code in IDE)

[image: Terminal error]

**eslint-config.json**

```
{
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": ["react-app", "airbnb"],
    "settings": {
      "import/resolver": {
        "node": {
          "paths": ["src"],
          "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",     /* Recommended React Native TSConfig base */
  "compilerOptions": {
    "skipLibCheck": true,                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
    "baseUrl": "src",
  },
}
```

In this image you can see my file structure, the error on my simulator. And how I am importing it.

[image]

I have two exported functions in my Text.tsx
export function Title
&
export function P

Any help is appreciated... Thank you!

Comment: can you please send us the folder structure of your project and where is the views folder?

Comment: Hi, @NishargShah I have included the file structure in the last image. If this is not sufficient, let me know!

Answer (score 1):

I will not suggest you to go with this flow because it's very confusing.

Suppose you had imported this `react/client` thing.

- Is it the npm package that contains subpath
- Is it my folder structure pathname

So I suggest you to go with the flow that most of the developers are using currently.

```
import Text from "@/views/Text";
```

I made one demo for you also, please check https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-dew-wn2rsu

**Note**

- Use `eslint-plugin-import` for removing import errors.

Comment: Hey! I am not doubting that this is the correct approach. But I struggling to understand what I need to add from that codesandbox. I have installed eslint-plugin-import and @typescript-eslint/parser. I have added baseUrl and paths from the sandbox. I have added the import Text from "@/views/Text" - but "...text/text could not be found within the project or in these directories: node modules". Also it suggests in the docs to use .eslintrc.js and seems different to your approach. So I am just unsure, could you please clarify? Thanks, Jack

Comment: If you are using `eslint` in your project then you need to set up that plugin because without that eslint will not identify that. please check https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files for your `.eslintrc.js` question

Answer (score 1):

In my case (react-native: 0.73.1) I was able to resolve it by enabling global package option in

```
//metro.config.js

const config = {
  resolver: {
    enableGlobalPackages: true,
    // ...
  },
  // ...
}
```

Comment: This saved me a whole lot of time

Answer (score 0):

create new `package.json` file under "src" folder and add `{ "name": "PATH_NAME" }`